# {{ obj.photos.url }} not showing images

Tags: django, listview, django-templates, django-class-based-views, detailview

----------------------- root urls.py  ------------------------------

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('estate.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

----------------------- app urls.py ------------------------------

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import index, about, category, PostListView, PostDetailView


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('category/', views.category, name='category'),
    path('liste/', PostListView.as_view(), name='liste'),
    path('detail/<int:id>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='detail-list'),
```

----------------------- models.py ----------------------

```
class lists(models.Model):
    ...
    photos = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/')
    ...
    def __str__ (self):
    return self.title
```

----------------------- views.py -----------------------

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
    from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
    from .models import *

    def index(request):
        listings = lists.objects.filter(is_active=True)
        hit10 = lists.filter().order_by('-hit_counter')[:10]


        context = {
            'listings':listings, 
            'hit10':hit10,
            }

        return render(request, 'index.html', context)


    class PostListView(ListView):
        queryset = lists.objects.filter(is_active=True)
        paginate_by = 5


    class PostDetailView(DetailView):

        def get_object(self):
            id_=self.kwargs.get("id")
            return get_object_or_404(listings, id=id_)
```

----------------------- template.py -----------------------

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}


<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Photo</th>
        <th scope="col">Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    {% for obj in object_list %}
        {% if obj.is_active %}
        <tbody>

            <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ obj.id }}</th>
            <td>{{ obj.photo.url }}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'detail-list' obj.id %} ">{{ obj.title }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ obj.date }}</td>

            </tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
</table>


{% endblock content %}
```

THERE IS NO THUMBNAIL SHOWING THE RESULT FOR IMAGE IS LIKE THAT : /media/photo/01.jpg

everythink else is fine. Thank you.

Comment: Poorly written post... Please make it more understandable.

Comment: Please provide some code samples. Probably you need to so something like {% for obj in object_list %}
   <img src="{{obj.photos.url}}" alt="photo"/>
{% endfor %}

Answer (score 0):

The image won't show because you didn't put the url in a image html tag.
Modified the template.html file:

```
...
<td> <img src=/static/{{ obj.photo.url }}></td>
...
```

Note:'static' should be your STATIC_URL which you set in settings.py.

Comment: but these are dynamic contents not static

Comment: those images are static, their url are store in the database, and the image file should be in other directory in your project.

Comment: thank you but, my static files are in /static/ and my other images etc are in a other directory named /media/

Answer (score 0):

i found the reason;

in template.py

```
    <tr>
                                 <th scope="row">{{ obj.id }}</th>
 THIS CODE SHOULD BE --->        <td>{{ obj.photo.url }}</td>
                                 <td><a href="{% url 'detail-list' obj.id %} ">{{ obj.title }}</a></td>
                                 <td>{{ obj.date }}</td>
                                 </tr>





     <tr>
                       <th scope="row">{{ obj.id }}</th>
 LIKE THIS ONE --->    <td><img  style="width:50%;" class="img-thumbnail" src="{{obj.photo.url}}" alt="IMG"></td>
                       <td><a href="{% url 'detail-list' obj.id %} ">{{ obj.title }}</a></td>
                       <td>{{ obj.date }}</td>
                                 </tr>
```

thanks to everyone who was helping especially to @Adil Shirinov.